# Feathers.js - аутентификация по двум связкам

Tags: node.js, аутентификация, feathersjs

Добавляю аутентификацию для пользователей при помощи генератора Feathers.js:

```
feathers generate authentication
```

По умолчанию добавляется аутентицикация только по связке email + пароль. Требуется добавить аутентификаию по второй связке: логин + пароль. Обе связки должны работать одновременно. Таким образом пользователь должен иметь возможность ввести как email, так и логин.
Изменения в default.json ни к чему не привели. Догадываюсь, что нужно изменить данный блок:

```
"local": {
      "entity": "user",
      "usernameField": "login",
      "passwordField": "password"
    }
```

Как можно добавить аутентификацию по второй связке?